# How to install the aws sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rubygems

When I run the command on my rails app

```
gem install aws-sdk
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing aws-sdk:
invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /Users/grantspilsbury/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/cache/aws-sdk-core-2.0.43.gem
```

I am trying to use Amazon's S3 storage service.

My gemfile includes

```
ruby "2.2.1"
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gem install aws-sdk -v 2.0.42` works for me.

Can you specify your system configuration?. I have had similar issues with ruby versions in past for mac os, so just confirming

Comment: Thank you. Was getting the error with aws-sdk-core (2.0.43)

Answer (score 0):

It should be an issue with the cached gem file (probably a corrupted file).
Try removing the gem file

```
/Users/UserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-VERSION/cache/GemName-GemVersion.gem
```

and then try again `'gem install GemName -v GemVersion'` or `'bundle install'`